# Chrome delay on font-awesome icons transition

Tags: css, delay, transition, font-awesome

Inside a navbar I have a delay of FA icons transition effect due to this CSS transition:

```
.navbar-nav > li > a > p > i {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

which is executed after (on Chrome):

```
.navbar-nav > li > a {
    text-align:center;
    color: #475347 !important;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
```

The navbar: http://jsfiddle.net/wtpLphw1/

But I need this the transition of `.navbar-nav > li > a > p > i` for the shrink transition effect of FA icons, when scrolling down the page.

JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $("nav").addClass("shrink");
    } else {
        $("nav").removeClass("shrink");
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
nav.shrink .navbar-nav > li > a > p > i {
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

I don't have this delay issue with Firefox or Edge.

But it's because Chrome execute first the transition of .`navbar-nav > li > a` and then the transition of `.navbar-nav > li > a > p > i.` We can see it clearly on Chrome with this fork having 1.3 sec for the first transition: https://jsfiddle.net/767psdwt

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you don't have to create an animation on text and icon separately, just delete this:

```
.navbar-nav > li > a > p > i {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    /*transition: all 0.3s ease-out;*/
}
```

I also decreased your animation duration, just fyi.

To keep the animation of font scaling, use this:

```
transition: font-size 0.3s ease-out;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/767psdwt/1/

Comment: But If I remove this transition, then the FA icons are not animated any more on scroll down and I would like them to be animated.

Comment: Oh yes, perfect! Thanks :) Do you know why there is a delay on scroll up and not on scroll down: http://www.cjoint.com/doc/17_01/GAjthoALMfH_delay-scroll-up.jpg

Comment: add transition: all 0.3s linear; to nav.navbar

Comment: Indeed I can see it! :)